# What's wrong with this while condition?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, while-loop, conditional-statements

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public const int N = 10;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[] word = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
            int i = 0, j = 0;
            Console.WriteLine(word);
            while ((word[i] >= 'a' && word[i] <= 'z') || (word[i] >= 'A' && word[i] <= 'Z'))
            {
                j++;
                i++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(+j);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Every time I try to debug, the debbuger tells me "IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled" and I don't know the reason why.

Comment: You never check the length of the `word` array.  If all the characters are letters, then the loop will continue until `i` is beyond the end of the array and then you will get the exception.

Comment: Tip: before asking question make sure to search for error message/exception name (like https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+IndexOutOfRangeException), if you still decide to ask question follow [MCVE] guidelines to provide minimal code with all necessary information inline (i.e. in this case `"A".ToCharArray()[1]`")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just not checking for the length of the array and continuously checking for elements which cause the `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Add this condition and it will work

```
while (i < word.Length && (word[i] >= 'a' && word[i] <= 'z') || (word[i] >= 'A' && word[i] <= 'Z'))
{
   j++;
   i++;
}
```

You should also know why `IndexOutOfRangeException` is thrown and what it means refer - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are incrementing `i` and `j` at each iteration of the while loop, but you never exit the loop.

```
char[] word = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
```

What happens when `i` becomes a value larger than the line read in from the console? You get the `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Perhaps think of when you would want to stop incrementing `i`, and break out of the loop.

Comment: ..the question smells of homework.. I've answered accordingly and just didn't provide the solution, but rather have the poster think about how to solve.

Answer (score 2):

The above answers already provided sufficient information about the problem. I guess I will just add on the outcome.

If you only want to display the alphabets, simply put a checks if the input letters/words are alphabet characters or space then display the letters/words, else return the invalid error message.

Here's the complete tested class for your reference.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WhileLoop
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string words = Console.ReadLine();

            //input words
            Console.WriteLine(words);


            //check not alphabet or space, return invalid error message
            Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z ]+");
            if (rgx.IsMatch(words))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please input alphabet or space only Ie. A-Z, a-z,");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Scenario#1 - Input non-alphabet characters
[image]

Scenario#2 - Input alphabet characters and space (EXPECTED RESULT)
[image]

Comment: The OPs code was counting the number of leading alphabetic characters in a string, but this is interesting too.